# How to create a shared julia environment for all users?

Tags: julia, centos7

Environment:
CentOS 7 64bit

a) created system user ds:

```
useradd -r -s /sbin/nologin ds
```

b) downloaded julia executable tar and extracted to /opt/julia:

```
tar -xvf "/tmp/downloads/julia/julia-1.3.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz" -C "/opt/julia"
```

c) made ds as owner of folders and files of /opt/julia and its sub folders:

```
chown -R "ds:ds" "/opt/julia"
```

I would like to setup shared julia environment for all users.

Please guide me in setting up the following, in the shared environment for all the users:

```
a) history
b) JULIA_HOME
c) JULIA_LOAD_PATH
d) JULIA_DEPOT_PATH
e) JULIA_PKG_DEVDIR
f) JULIA_PROJECT
g) PATH
h) security
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note: this proposed solution is valid for Ubuntu. Paths may be different in CentOS, but the process should be the same.*

The solution I ended up for a similar scenario was to share only the Julia binaries (those downloaded from Julialang.org) expanding them in `/lib/julia-1.x/` (with a symlink to `/lib/julia.x/bin/julia` in `/bin`) and let each user to have its own ~/.julia folder.

In this way you avoid the mess of having package versions that are not compatible between the global package repository and the local one.

If you go trough this configuration, you can add a script to  `/usr/local/sbin/adduser.local` that will be executed any time you add a new user with `adduser`.

For example I added:

`su $1 -c "julia /usr/bin/initJuliaRepository.jl"` where in turn I pre-install on each users a set of commonly used packages:

```
import Pkg

Pkg.update()
Pkg.add("IJulia")
Pkg.add("DataFrames")
Pkg.add("Plots")
Pkg.build("IJulia")
```